How to change a Facebook password with a new phone number?
It looks like the only way to fix an inability to access either e-mail or SMS is to delete the account.  Once the account is deleted, does that free up the e-mail address?
On my old phone, I'm logged into facebook using my e-mail address.  When I try "forgot the password" it wants to send a SMS message.  However, my phone number has changed.
On the new phone, when I try to add the e-mail address I get a message that it's already in use.  Which I know.
my previous phone number xxxxxxxxxx
my new phone number xxxxxxxxxx
So, on my iPhone with the new number I have an account only with the phone number.
On my old phone I have an account only with my e-mail and an out of date phone number, and so cannot authenticate.
Perhaps there's a way to merge these accounts?

Can you clarify if you are using the IOS Facebook app?

yes, using the iOS Facebook app on an iPhone.  On an Android phone, using Google app.  And using the website.  The iOS Facebook app is tied to a phone number but not to an e-mail account.  The website and Android app are tied to an e-mail account but an old phone number.
